# Docker / congifparser error in requirements.txt

Tags: python, docker, pip, requirements.txt

In my code I'm using configparser:

```
from configparser import ConfigParser
```

And I'm using pip freeze to generate my requirements.txt

```
pip freeze > requirements.txt
```

And for configparser it's writing

```
configparser==3.3.0.post2
```

But that fails when I do a `pip install -r requirements.txt` from within the docker container via a docker build:

```
docker build -t denzel .

Downloading/unpacking configparser==3.3.0.post2 (from -r /home/denzel/requirements.txt (line 2))
Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement configparser==3.3.0.post2 (from -r /home/denzel/requirements.txt (line 2)) (from versions: 3.2.0r1, 3.2.0r2, 3.2.0r3, 3.3.0r1, 3.3.0r2, 3.5.0b1, 3.5.0b2)
Cleaning up...
No distributions matching the version for configparser==3.3.0.post2 (from -r /home/denzel/requirements.txt (line 2))
```

But this works locally via `pip install`:

```
 pip install -r requirements.txt
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): aniso8601==1.1.0 in ./env/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from -r requirements.txt (line 1))
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): configparser==3.3.0.post2 in ./env/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from -r requirements.txt (line 2))
....
....
```

NOTE: I fixed this by removing the version and just using `configparser`, no version. Still wanted to post my question to get the reason why it's failing.

Comment: Different versions of pip, maybe?  What version are you running locally?  What version is in use in your container?  What if you upgrade pip first (`pip install -U pip`)?

Comment: Can you post your Dockerfile? Likely there's a config issue as implied by @larsks

Answer (score 0):

**Following will work with docker**

app.py

```
from configparser import ConfigParser
config = ConfigParser()
config.read('app.conf')
_var = config.get(‘Section’, 'Status')

print (_var)
```

requirements.txt

```
configparser
```

**Following will work locally**

app.py

```
import ConfigParser
config = ConfigParser.ConfigParser()
config.read('app.conf')
_var = config.get(‘Section’, 'Status')

print (_var)
```